# I forgot how to breathe...help

Tags: science

I have a problem.
I can't breathe. 
I woke up one day and I forgot.

**How long do I live?**

This is my first question...
I hope I don't make a mistake.

Hint,but basically the answer

> am I alive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you're not alive, then you must live forever (or as long as you exist).

Comment: Well done,but did you use the hint?

Comment: That's what hints are for, isn't it?

Comment: I've fixed it now,it used to be the answer...

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a conceptual level question. 
We can take this to a spiritual level.

So the question, what if we forget to breath.

There may be many views, but the best possible one 4 me  - thinking in a spiritual way is

Probably you had left your physical body and your thinking has grown to such a level that even you forget to breath while immersing yourself in meditation / spiritual path[what ever you calls.].

If you sustain in that state for a long time, probably your friends and family will see you as a picture in wall :-p. And unfortunately you may not aware of the things as your soul has separated from body.

Comment: You did well,good point,but the question needs to be answered.